# output where pandas Series of booleans is True

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Series created like this

```
s = pd.Series({'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False, 'd': True, 'e': False})

>> s
a    False
b     True
c    False
d     True
e    False
dtype: bool
```

Is there a way to neatly extract the names of where it is True, staying within Pandas or NumPy and without going back to ordinary Python?

At the moment I am using this:

```
sdict = s.to_dict()
for item in list(sdict):
    if sdict[item] == True:
        print (item, end=" ")

>> b d
```

Comment: `s.index[s]` will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `s.index`:

```
print (s.index[s])
Index(['b', 'd'], dtype='object')

print (s.index[s].tolist())
['b', 'd']

print (', '.join(s.index[s]))
b, d
```

A bit overcomplicated solution with `np.where`, for fun:

```
print (s.index[np.where(s)[0]])
Index(['b', 'd'], dtype='object')
```